# How do I correctly append Table rows and do mass saving into a database in laravel and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Am creating an inventory or sells system, I want to add rows when ***addRow*** is clicked. Currently, am able to add the rows but unable to insert all the added rows into the database. only the first two rows are inserted into the database when I save. The other rows doesn't. Please How can I save all rows when I add new row. This is my code below;

**Blade.php**

```
       <form method="POST" action="{{URL::to('/new-invoice')}}">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <div class="card-title">
                  <span><button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Invoice</button></span>
                  <span><button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Save</button></span>
                  <span><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Refresh</button></span>
                  <span><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print</button></span>
                </div>

                <div class="card-tools">
                  <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                    <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search">

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 300px;">
                <table class="table table-head-fixed text-nowrap" id="myTable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Qty</th>
                      <th>Item</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                      <th>Unit Price</th>
                      <th>Tax</th>
                      <th>Total</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="number" name="items[0][inv_quantity]" class="form-control quantity" style="width: 70px"></td>
                      <td>
                        <select name="items[0][inv_item]" class="form-control item" style="width: 250px">
                          <option>Items</option>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_desc]" class="form-control description" style="width: 400px"></td>
                      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_price]" class="form-control u_price" style="width: 150px"></span></td>
                      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_tax]" class="form-control tax" style="width: 150px"></td>
                      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_total]" class="form-control amount" style="width: 150px"></td>
                      <td>
                        <span><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span>
                        <span><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Row</button></span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>

                    
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </div>
        </div>



        <script type="text/javascript">

          function myFunction() {
            var x = 0;
            x++;
            var tr = '<tr>'+
             '<td><input type="number" name="items['+x+'][inv_quantity]" class="form-control" style="width: 70px"></td>'+ '<td><select name="items['+x+'][inv_item]" class="form-control" style="width: 250px"><option>Items</option></select></td>'+'<td><input type="text" name="items['+x+'][inv_desc]" class="form-control" style="width: 400px"></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+x+'][inv_price]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px"></span></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+x+'][inv_tax]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px"></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+x+'][inv_total]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px"></td>'+'<td><span><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><span><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Row</button></span</td>'
             '</tr>';
             $('tbody').append(tr);
          }


          
        </script>

        </form>
```

**Contoller.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request::all();

        if(array_key_exists('items', $data)) {
            foreach($data['items'] as $item) {
                Invoice::insert([
                    'inv_qty' => $item['inv_quantity'],
                    'inv_item' => $item['inv_item'],
                    'inv_desc' => $item['inv_desc'],
                    'inv_unit_price' => $item['inv_price'],
                    'inv_tax' => $item['inv_tax'],
                    'inv_total' => $item['inv_total'],
                ]);
            }
        }
        return back();
    }
```

Please how can I correctly do this in laravel and javascript?

Comment: How you are submitting your form data?

Comment: I don't get your question please, but i want to be able to save all added rows into the database.. That is, if i add new row fields, i want to be able to insert all into the database by click on ***Save***.  Currently am able to successfully save only two of the Columns into the database even when I have 5 rows of inserted fields

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.. Thank you

```
<form method="POST" action="{{URL::to('/new-invoice')}}">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <div class="card-title">
                  <span><button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Invoice</button></span>
                  <span><button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Save</button></span>
                  <span><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Refresh</button></span>
                  <span><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print</button></span>
                </div>

                <div class="card-tools">
                  <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                    <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search">

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 300px;">
                <table class="table table-head-fixed text-nowrap" id="myTable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Qty</th>
                      <th>Item</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                      <th>Unit Price</th>
                      <th>Tax</th>
                      <th>Total</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="number" name="items[0][inv_quantity]" class="form-control quantity" style="width: 70px"></td>
                      <td>
                        <select name="items[0][inv_item]" class="form-control item" style="width: 250px">
                          <option>Items</option>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_desc]" class="form-control description" style="width: 400px"></td>
                      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_price]" class="form-control u_price" style="width: 150px"></span></td>
                      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_tax]" class="form-control tax" style="width: 150px"></td>
                      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_total]" class="form-control amount" style="width: 150px"></td>
                      <td>
                        <span><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span>
                        <span><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Row</button></span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>

                    
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </div>
        </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
          var int = 1;
          function myFunction() {
            var tr = '<tr>'+
             '<td><input type="number" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_quantity]" class="form-control" style="width: 70px"></td>'+ '<td><select name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_item]" class="form-control" style="width: 250px"><option>Items</option></select></td>'+'<td><input type="text" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_desc]" class="form-control" style="width: 400px"></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_price]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px"></span></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_tax]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px"></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_total]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px"></td>'+'<td><span><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><span><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Row</button></span</td>'
             '</tr>';
             $('tbody').append(tr);
             int++;
          }



        </script>
```

***Controller.php***

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request::all();

        if(array_key_exists('items', $data)) {
            foreach($data['items'] as $item) {
                Invoice::insert([
                    'inv_qty' => $item['inv_quantity'],
                    'inv_item' => $item['inv_item'],
                    'inv_desc' => $item['inv_desc'],
                    'inv_unit_price' => $item['inv_price'],
                    'inv_tax' => $item['inv_tax'],
                    'inv_total' => $item['inv_total'],
                ]);
            }
        }
        return back();
    }
```